# Cocos2d-iphone v2 and RestKit

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, xcode4.3, restkit

I try to install RestKit (throu CocoaPods) to my Cocos2d project. It goes fine but when I try to build my project I got 38 errors with libPods.a at github they told me that is a problem with my options. I should set $(inherited) in all suboptions in "search paths". I did it but beside that I have `<myproject>/libs/kazmath/include` in **Header Search Paths** and `<myproject>/libs` in **User Header Search Paths** [[screen shots]](http://www.dropmocks.com/mBlV20).
When I delete those lien and left only $(inherited) then build fail because "kazmath.h was not found."

Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never forget about building whole workspace, if you build only one project, without pods it works only on iOS device.